# Error in login to the uri 'analytics-dashboard'. Error: AM_SYSTEM_APPS does not exist in the AM_DB database -in analytics quick setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After running worker-wso2ApiManager-dahsboard, https://localhost:9643/analytics-dashboard/login throws following exception in analytics quick setup :

> Error in login to the uri 'analytics-dashboard'. Error: AM_SYSTEM_APPS
> does not exist in the AM_DB database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quick setup what you have to do is first get the fresh APIM pack(its name is wso2am-3.2.0) and Analytics pack. so the structure you have to provide like following.

```
-------- wso2am-3.2.0
-------- wso2am-analytics-3.2.0
```

The name of the APIM product folder is wso2am-3.2.0.

(simply you can go inside wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml file and you can check whether the defined jdbcUrl of AM_DB path(AM_DB is inside the APIM product folder) is correct)

```
Ex: /../wso2am-3.2.0/repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;
```

If you didn't place wos2am-3.1.0 product folder in the same directory which has the analytics folder, then you run the analytics dashboard, it automatically creates a folder name wso2am-3.2.0 and it's not working. So first you need to place the product folder correctly.